# Laravel Crinsane Shopping cart install migration

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Has anyone installed [Crinsane/shoppingcart](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart) ?

In the installation documentation there is no mention of the migration for the table. There is no mention of the configuration of the database connection.
I can only assume that I am not very experienced with laravel, and it is probably something obvious that I do not know about.

Anyway: there is a config/cart.php file (in the vendor) where I found the database connection setting, but I have no idea on how to change it to make it work (I can only assume that I should change it because, of course, there is no table called shoppingcart in my application's database after I did my composer installation).

So I have this section in the cart.php file:

```
 'database' => [

        'connection' => null,

        'table' => 'shoppingcart',

    ],
```

How should I set this up? What do I write in the "connection"?

After installation, my Cart is working but it has a strange behavior, and I can only guess that it happens because there is no DB table anywhere that would hold the cart data.

The strange behavior is that when I add an item to the cart, it ends up in the cart but when I refresh the page, the cart gets empty. But when I add 2-3 products to the cart, and then refresh the page, the cart contains all the items (minus the one that I added to the cart before). Also after I add the first product, when I try to add a new item to the cart it does not do it on the first click on AddToCart button. But when I click again, the second product gets added to the cart

I am sure I am doing something wrong, Can anyone help me with a more detailed installation tutorial?

**EDIT**

I ran the migration, and now I have the shoppingcart table in my database (without changing the database connection in the config.php file)

The behavior is the same. Nothing's changed
What should I do?

Comment: i have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Use the methods:

```
Cart::store($this->authUser->id);
Cart::restore($this->authUser->id);
```